# Java Radio Button anomaly

Tags: java, radio-button

I am writing a Java application, and I have four radio buttons, call them rb1, rb2, rb3, and rb4.  I've added two of them to one radiobutton group, and the other two to a second radio buttongroup. Then I added all four of them to a panel.  Distinct action listeners are defined for all four buttons.

However, when I click on the first button in one group it fires its own action listener and the one for the second button in the other group.  That button that incorrectly fires won't fire at all when I click on it.

I can only suspect that they shouldn't all be in one panel, but that seems a bit strained as an explanation.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any help.

John Doner

Comment: You might have to show some code. I can think of no reason why adding them all to a single panel will cause this problem.

Comment: I've put multiple button groups in the same container.  I would suspect that you messed up adding the action listeners, and the "one for the second button in the other group" is actually attached to one in the same group.  Remember that when you click on a radio button, you're going to get two action listener events, one on the button being selected and another on the one being deselected.

Comment: A code might be nice ... i could not reproduce the error with mine!

Comment: @John try to provide an example in order to clarify your question, but I agree that somehow you mixed the listeners actions or the raddio buttons following your explanation!!

Comment: The way you explained it, it sounds like you added the actual buttons to the JPanel. Make sure that you added the radiobutton groups to the panel, not the individual buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly fine for several groups of radio buttons to live in the same panel.

Double check your listeners. Check that listener4 was actually added to rb4. You may actually have done this instead:

```
rb1.addActionListener(listener1);
rb2.addActionListener(listener2);
rb3.addActionListener(listener3);
rb1.addActionListener(listener4);  // NOTE: listener added to rb1 instead of rb4
```

If this is what happened, then:

- Clicking on rb1 would fire listener1 and listener4
- Clicking on rb4 would do nothing (no listener attached to it)

Which seems to match your symptoms.

Comment: You were right! Amazing how many times I can review my own code and miss a glaring error!   Thanks.